# Go programming cross compile for revel framework

Tags: go, arm, cross-compiling, revel

I am using the Revel framework to make a web application.
I am cross compiling it for ARM with the command
`GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm revel package mitm`

This works fine, however I have just included the library `github.com/google/gopacket`

and now the cross compiled build fails (it runs fine on OSX that I am developing on).

I get:

> ERROR 2015/07/27 09:01:30 build.go:101: # mitm/app/controllers
>   go/src/webserver/app/controllers/ArpScan.go:88: undefined:
>   pcap.OpenLive go/src/webserver/app/controllers/ArpScan.go:88:
>   undefined: pcap.BlockForever
>   go/src/webserver/app/controllers/ArpScan.go:114: undefined:
>   pcap.Handle go/src/webserver/app/controllers/ArpScan.go:145:
>   undefined: pcap.Handle

pcap is a library imported from gopacket:

`import "github.com/google/gopacket/pcap`"

My question is how do I get it to cross compile this library aswell?

I ran Dave Cheney's `go-crosscompile-build-all` ([link](http://dave.cheney.net/2012/09/08/an-introduction-to-cross-compilation-with-go)) but that just builds the standard library.

Comment: That package uses cgo, do you have a C compiler for the target architecture?

Comment: Ahh ok, so I need a cross platform C compiler on my mac to be able to compile that library for ARM?
Do you have a link to some tutorial? how do I check if I have a C compiler for that architecture? I've not knowingly installed one. What are the steps once I do have one?

Comment: I don't have an OS X machine, so I can't really help with that. Look for cross-compilers in the brew repos, and if there aren't any, look up the instructions to build them.

Comment: Try this: https://github.com/tpoechtrager/osxcross (and then realize what a huge pain cross-compiling C across OS' & architectures is and just boot a small Ubuntu VM with build-essential & the Go toolchain installed via https://github.com/travis-ci/gimme)

Comment: So I have had minor improvements... 
I pulled the latest go (1.4.2 src code). I ran `bash all.bash` and that seemed successful. When I run `C=arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm revel package mitm` I get the error: "go build runtime: linux/arm must be bootstrapped using make.bash"
I then run `GOOS=linux GOARCH=arm ./make.bash --no-clean` which is successful, however that doesnt allow revel to build successfully

Comment: You can try getting go1.5beta2 where cross-compiling is done [much easier](https://medium.com/@rakyll/go-1-5-cross-compilation-488092ba44ec). Go 1.5 itself should be out next month.

Comment: You may be interested in this post that address the problems of hidden Cgo in the standard library as well as a potential solution (gonative).   https://inconshreveable.com/04-30-2014/cross-compiling-golang-programs-with-native-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

Try [goxc](https://github.com/laher/goxc). It requires the go source and the go toolchain but works well.